# Problem migrating Entity Reference fields with Drupal 7

Tags: 7, migrations

I cannot migrate entity reference fields [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) . I am following the examples online i.e.

`$this->addFieldMapping('my_reference_field','bla')->sourceMigration('BooksNode')->separator(',');`

The idea is for a book lending data. I can lend several books to one person (not a user on my site, just a regular content type).

Not sure what I am missing but nothing gets mapped.

I should add that the primary key on my Books table (in MySQL) is a composite one consisting of two fields id and unique_id. Do I need to add that somehow to :

`$this->addFieldMapping('my_reference_field','bla')->sourceMigration('BooksNode')->separator(',');`

maybe

`$this->addFieldMapping('my_reference_field',array('id', 'unique_id'))->sourceMigration('BooksNode')->separator(',');`

thx in advance

Comment: Is anything being written in the Messages area for your migration?